# Bootstrap 4 Modal Background not responsive on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#loginerrormodal').modal('show');
    });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="loginerrormodal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content bg-white">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">...</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run the modal on mobile, the black background isn't responsive:
(the modal opes at page load so I don't have buttons to launch it)

[image: This is what I mean]

How I can fix?

Comment: Can you post all the code so I could reproduce it? Like, the button to open modal and part of CSS.

Comment: @Azametzin Done. In this code there isn't custom css.

Comment: Can you post your index.html?

Comment: Do you have a live-version of this? Because with all the info we have, there are no issues for now. It is something else.

Comment: @Azametzin https://codepen.io/alex3025/pen/ZgYPOg
But on there it seems work perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's possible to see in the live version you provided, there is an element exceeding the total width of the device, which is disturbing the modal.

Find the `<div>` with classes "card", "bg-white" and "mx-auto" and remove the inline style of `width: 30rem` for mobile devices breakpoint (480px).

If that's not possible, you can create a media query using `!important` to override the inline style, like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { // the breakpoint that the problem is ocurring
  .card.bg-white.mx-auto {
    width: 100% !important; // it should work instead of 30rem
  }
}
```

Comment: This is for the card not the modal, and where I find `inline style`?

Comment: Yes, because the card `witdh` is creating the issue. The `inline style` is already typed or being created somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I fix with this:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```